# Make an equivalence relation on the set $A = \{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$.

Tags: equivalence-relations

> The set $A = \{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ is given. Write one equivalence relation from this set, write the equivalence classes and write the elements of the quotient set, and in the end on the set $B = \{1,2,3,4\}$ write the equivalence relation that has binomial ($2$-member) quotient set.

For the first part of the problem involving set A, the equivalence relation I wrote is: 
\begin{gather}\{(1,1),(2,2),(3,3),(4,4),(5,5),\\(6,6),(1,2),(2,1),(2,3),(3,2),(3,5),(5,3)(3,6),(6,3)\}\end{gather}
Is my equivalence relation correct ?
Equivalence classes:
$$ [1] = \{1,2\} , [2] = \{2,1,3\} , [3] = \{3,2,5\} , [4] = \{4\}, 
[5] = \{5,3\} , [6] = \{6,3\}$$
Are they correct?

Elements of the quotient set : ??
Could you help me with this one ?

Second part of the problem involving set B, I don't know how to solve so could you help me with this one as well ?

Comment: No, your relation is not an equivalence relation. It's reflexive and symmetric but not transitive.

Comment: Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: You could just write $\{(1,1)\}$

Comment: One of the ideas of equivalence classes is that all elements within a class are equivalent. That is, if, for instance, $1 \in [2]$, then we should have $[1] = [2]$. That is not the case for your relation. Also, the "quotient set" is just the set of equivalence classes.

Comment: @windircurse That would not be an equivalence relation on $A$

Comment: @windircurse That relation is not reflexive on $A$.

Comment: You can always define a trivial equivalence relation $\{(x,x)|x\in A\}$

Comment: So, for example if equivalence classes are : [1],[2],[3] the "quotient set" would be {[1],[2],[3]} ? @Arthur

Comment: Yes, that's it. For another example, if your equivalence relation is "have the same parity as", then the two equivalence classes would be $[1]=[3]=[5] = \{1, 3, 5\}$ and $[2]=[4]=[6]=\{2, 4, 6\}$, and the quotient set is $\{[1],[2]\}$.